# Cannot boot Windows 10 from dual boot Linux

Tags: windows, multi-boot, uefi

I don’t know what I did, now I want to come back to the Windows from Linux but when my laptop shows this display, I click on the Windows Boot Manager (on/dev/nvme0n1p1) for 2 or 3 times and it displays this. What is my problem? How can I reinstall the Windows?

[image: Pic1]

[image: Pic2]

Comment: Looks like some kind of UEFI firmware problem that is related to Secure Boot. Wonder if you can even fix it by reinstalling Windows. (You might even be able to boot to Windows if you use your UEFI boot menu to do it instead.)

Comment: [This](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1401737/couldnt-create-moklist-volume-full-grub-doesnt-start-at-all) is definitely a Secure Boot problem, you can probably avoid reinstalling Windows, by just disabling Secure Boot.

Comment: Do you wish to stay only with Windows and without dual boot? (Add to your comment `@harrymc` for me to be notified.)